# laravel 5 one to one relationship show foreign key name field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database, laravel-5

Okey so, I have two tables: (they have more columns but these are the important ones)

Projects
id PK AI
customer_id (FK customers)

Customer
id PK AI
name

Now, on my index page, I want to show the projects listen in a table and in the "customer" column I want to show the name of the customer and not the ID, cause the ID means nothing to the person who's going to view the table.

For some reason though, I can't get it to work. I have googled and researched on how to do this without success..so I hope I can get an answer here of what I'm doing wrong.

This is my set up:

Project.php

```
<?php namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model {

protected $table = 'projects';

protected $fillable = [
    'customer_id', 'user_owner', 'user_project_leader' , 'name', 'description', 'status', 'offered_price',
    'estimate', 'project_start', 'deadline', 'free_text', 'total_price', 'created_at', 'updated_at'

];

public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Customer');
}

}
```

Customer.php

```
<?php namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model {

protected $table = 'customers';

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'reference_person', 'created_at', 'updated_at'

];

}
```

ProjectsController.php

```
public function index(){          
$projects = Project::with('customer')->get();
return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
}
```

And finally, my index.php

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $project->user_owner }}</td>
      @foreach($project->customer as $pcustomer)
      <td>{{ $pcustomer->name }}</td>
      @endforeach
      <td>{{ $project->deadline }}</td>
      <td>{{ $project->offered_price }}</td>
      <td> 00h</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

The error I'm getting is "Class Customer not found". When it's clearly there in my folder and used in other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you run `composer dump-autoload`.

Second things  - I think you need to use:

```
return $this->hasOne('\App\models\Customer');
```

in your relation

Comment: I did those two things you suggested and now it finds the class but gives me this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customers.project_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `customers` where `customers`.`project_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4))

I can see it's searching for a column that doesn't excist, I'm just not sure why.

Comment: You should probably change your relationship into return `$this->belongsTo('\App\models\Customer');`

Comment: Thank you! I have a hard time understanding this but now that I got it to work I have something to start with. I successfully made the name appear by doing that change and calling it using <td>{{ $project->customer->name }}</td>